# Opening a pdf and opening a specific page

Tags: c++, pdf

I am trying to open a pdf at a specific page when the user enters the       correct number, I've been looking around but am lost with the windows.h not sure  what to do next, here's my code:

```
// DungeonsAndDragons.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application. //  
#include "stdafx.h" 
#include <iostream> 
#include "windows.h"  

using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]) {  
    int featsSpells;
    int select1;
    int select2; 
    int select3;
    string exit; 
    cout << "******Brad's DnD Feat/Spell Glossary*********" << endl;    
    cout << "Are you looking for Feats[#1] or Spells[#2]" << endl; 

    cin >> featsSpells; 

    if (featsSpells == 1){      
        ShellExecute(GetDesktopWindow(), "open", Argv[1],NULL,NULL,SHOWNORMAL); 
    }           
    system("pause"); 
    return 0;
}
```

The code does not compile because I get a complaint about `"const char *" is incompatible with parameter of type "LPCWSTR"`.

Comment: Did you already try if the `ShellExecute` thingy is working ?

Comment: yeah thats where im having a problem im not sure where to put the pdf file

Comment: 1 IntelliSense: argument of type "const char *" is incompatible with parameter of type "LPCWSTR" c:\Users\bradf_000\Desktop\DungeonsAndDragons\DungeonsAndDragons\DungeonsAndDragons.cpp 22 36 DungeonsAndDragons

Comment: ShellExecute(GetDesktopWindow(), "open", "C:\Users\bradf_000\Desktop\DungeonsAndDragons\Dungeons & Dragons D&D 5E 5th Ed - Player's Handbook - Color 150dpi OCR ToC", NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL); //this is giving me an error on the open and on the file path and name

Comment: Google how to convert from const char * to LPCWSTR. Put the pdf in c:\temp and address it absolutely

Comment: awesome i got it to open now i need it to open on a certain page haha thx

Comment: Append #page=123 or use one of the parameters you can find here: http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf. If this works I will create an answer to summarize all of this

Answer (score 1):

There are several things you should change.

The compiler / editor error is because you are mixing data types. You need to convert the `ARGV` into a `LPCWSTR`, because this is what `ShellExecute` expect.

To make sure that ShellExecute finds the .pdf you can specify the full path to the file, for example `C:\temp\foo.pdf` (if hardcoded into the source code you need to specify the backslash twice).

In order to tell the Acrobat reader (I think not all other alternative pdf viewer support this) on which page you want to start, you can append `#page=123`. Adobe documents the [list of possible parameters](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf) in a PDF in a - you guessed it ;-) - pdf file